# Is there a way to turn the hotspot on from Wifi to Wifi?

Tags: macos, mac, network, vpn

The situation is like this - I need to connect one Mac to the hotspot of another Mac.

Also has to be mentioned that the Mac that shares WiFi is connected through VPN, so the schema looks like this

```
first Mac -> connected VPN -> share the hotspot -> second Mac connected
```

I am using UrbanVPN which works as expected. When I open `System Prefs -> Sharing -> Hotspot from -> UrbanVPN`, and `hotspot to: wifi`. The problem is that with such a configuration I see a notification wifi is not connected. So, to put it differently, once I start sharing the connection wifi is disconnected.

I tried to figure out what is a possible problem and looks like Mac doesn't allow to share Wifi to Wifi as there is some problem with creating a virtual network.

So, to sum up, I need to connect my second Mac to the network (with altered ip - VPN), taking into account that I can't install VPN on this laptop. It is the reason I come up with the idea to install VPN on the first Mac and share the network.

Any ideas appreciated:)

**NOTE:** MacOS version: Ventura

Comment: This is confusing at best.  Are you trying to say you'd like to share the VPN connection of your Mac using Internet sharing?

Comment: @Allan yep, that is right. There is one mac connected with VPN and I try to share this VPN connecting to my other Mac.

Comment: Well, your Mac under Internet Sharing becomes a router.  When you connect to VPN, all traffic goes through a software interface which isn't shareable using Apple's built in Internet sharing; it uses *physical* interfaces.  Why not just install the VPN software on the second Mac?

Comment: @Allan, Yep, I agree it would be an easier option:) However, the problem is that I can't install 3rd parties software on the second Mac... It is a reason why I come up with such a workaround:) Let me please know if you have any suggestions for such a scenario

Comment: There is a lot in configuring this.  Start here for forwarding packets:  https://serverfault.com/q/791181

Comment: @Allan hmm, I feel like there is a lack of basic knowledge in order to solve what I intended to do. I'll try to figure it out, thanks for your answer:)

Comment: It's can get quite complex actually - it's not a simple task.  You have to manage IP addresses (DHCP) manage name resolution (DNS), ip packet forwarding, network address translation (NAT) and firewalling (PF).  Then you have to add in VPN to the mix.  It's a lot more than can be written in a single answer.

Comment: @Allan thank for you your reply!:) Ok, maybe you can suggest something that doesn't require so much effort? The thing I am trying to do is to connect my laptop to VPN, without installing VPN on this laptop. I heard there is another possible solution to buy a modern router which supports VPN out of the box. So, from my understanding, I can set up VPN on a router and connect my laptop to wifi (which has a "different" ip - VPN). Does it make sense?

Comment: You've got the solution - there are travel routers with VPN support meaning it will do "out of the box" everything you're trying to configure here.